# How do I remove this stubborn ceiling light fixture?

Tags: light-fixture

Please check the photograph of the light fixture.  All the bulbs have gone out and I cannot get the glass out to replace them. I unscrewed the decorative thing at the bottom. After that I unscrewed another bolt with washer but the glass is not moving. I'm not sure what to do after that. I'm trying to move the decorative thing on top of glass also, but it's moving at all.

[image: Light Fixture]

Comment: Could you please provide a closer picture of the threaded tube/washer/fittings at the bottom of the glass? I am almost 100% certain that once all nuts and finials are removed from that threaded tube, the glass will come off. Be careful it does not fall on your head.

Comment: The glass is probably being retained simply by friction and accumulated grime, if you've removed the hardware. You're lucky it hasn't fallen and broken... Try rotating it gently to see if you can determine what it's catching on.

Comment: Photography tip. Point the camera so the middle point in the image is over an area with some sharp edges, like the fancy moulding at the top, then shoot and crop later. On some cameras / phones you can select a suitable point to focus on instead - by tapping the view-screen or moving an X-Y control. On some cameras you can lock focus with a half press, then move the camera to frame the object and press fully.

Comment: Maybe the gold clips to the back plate in addition to the center screw.  The picture is not very clear.

Answer (score 1):

The light fixture *should* have come loose after loosening that nut.

Try the following:

- Get a step ladder or ladder and place it directly bellow the light.
- Get on the ladder :)
- Determine if the fixture is 2 separate pieces or 1 whole piece (glass + gold decorative ring)
- Carefully grab the light fixture with both hands and firmly turn the light fixture a few degrees in either direction. Be careful as the glass from the light fixture should come free.

If it does **not** it could be stuck ceiling due to paint or grime as someone mentioned in the comments.

If this is the case, try being a little more aggressive in your rotation, again being careful as it can slide free.

Answer (score 1):

Use a credit card as a prying tool on the stubborn glass dome to separate it from the fixture base. Slip the credit card in between the seam like you're slicing a piece of cake.
It should come off easily that way.

Answer (score 0):

The nut in the center should be all that is holding the glass. I think you need to look closely at the edge of the glass where it contacts the fixture for traces of an adhesive someone may have used and maybe pry gently with a plastic tool keeping the nut and washer on the threads like in the picture. Other than that I'm not sure without damaging the fixture.